# Ordering lists within a list in C#

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, sql-order-by

I need a push in the right direction with regards to ordering data using Linq.

I've got a list of People objects in C#, which in turn, holds a list of Sites that the person may be associated with.

Those Site objects holds is an instance of an Organisation object, that the site is associated with (as an organisation may have many sites..)

**Edit: A person will only belong to a single organisation in the list. (Thanks @jonskeet)**

How do I order the list of people, using Linq (or Lamba) to show them in alphabetical order, by their Organisation, and then ordered by the Surname, Firstname of the contact..??

Comment: Your requirements are unclear - what if a person belongs to more than one organization? Which should be used for sorting?

Comment: Ah, beg your pardon. The person will only belong to one organisation.

Comment: So why does a Person have a *list* of sites? It seems that the organization should be set on the person, not on each of the sites...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It strikes me that your model is a bit messed up, but if you're sure that:

- A person will have at least one site
- *All* the sites for a particular person will be for the same organization

you can use:

```
var sorted = people.OrderBy(p => p.Sites.First().Organization)
                   .ThenBy(p => p.LastName)
                   .ThenBy(p => p.FirstName);
```

Comment: It is a bit messed up, but that's another story! :-/

Comment: Close enough! Here's what I've had to use (for anyone else's reference):

Comment: sorted = people.OrderBy(x => x.Sites.FirstOrDefault().Organisation.Name).ThenBy(x => x.Surname).ThenBy(x => x.Firstname);

Comment: @Brett: You shouldn't use FirstOrDefault - that implies there *could* be an empty list of sites, in which case you'll end up with a null reference which will still go bang, but in a less obvious way.

Answer (score 0):

```
people.SelectMany(p => p.Sites).OrderBy(s => s.Organisation.Name).ThenBy(s => s.Organisation.Contact.Surname).ThenBy(s => s.Organisation.Contact.FirstName);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, but there's a list of Site objects in between the person and the organisation...

Answer (score 0):

Linq supports an order by clause. Check out this MSDN link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383982.aspx

### Example

```
public class CityLookup
{       public string City { get; set; }    
    public string Country { get; set; }
}

List<CityLookup> citiesLkp =            
new List<CityLookup>            
{       
    new CityLookup{ City = "New Delhi", Country = "India" },          
    new CityLookup{ City = "Sydney", Country = "Australia" },  
    new CityLookup{ City = "Tokyo", Country = "Japan" },                 
    new CityLookup{ City = "New York", Country = "USA" },                
    new CityLookup{ City = "Paris", Country = "France" },                
    new CityLookup{ City = "Barcelona", Country = "Spain" },                                          
};


// Now sort the names based on city name
var myList =    from c in citiesLkp    orderby c.City    select c;

foreach (var record in myList )    
{        
    Console.WriteLine(record.City);    
}
```

Comment: Is there anything else you can add? A code sample, maybe? Generally answers here are expected to be self-contained.